# Trying to get the average of a count resultset using sql server 2016

Tags: sql-server, average

I have the following SQL using SQL server 2016 (RTM-GDR) (KB4058560) - 13.0.1745.2 (X64) version:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS tot,
    PageView 
FROM
    [dbo].[LOG] 
GROUP BY
    PageView 
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC;
```

now I am getting this resultset

```
tot     PageView    
7893    APP 1
1476    APP 2
478     APP 3
```

I want to get the average daily accesses of this list

I did not get it to work

```
SELECT AVG(COUNT) AS avg,
       t 
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS COUNT,
        T.PageView t 
    FROM
        [dbo].[LOG] T 
    WHERE
        T.DateHour = (SELECT MAX (B.DateHour) FROM [dbo].[LOG] B WHERE (B.Id = T.Id)) 
    GROUP BY
        T.PageView 
    ) AS counts 
GROUP BY
    t;

avg     PageView
7893    APP 1
1476    APP 2
478     APP 3
```

My table structure below

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for LOG
-- ----------------------------   
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LOG] (
  [id] bigint  IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [user] nvarchar(10) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  NULL,
  [PageView] nvarchar(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  NULL,
  [DateHour] smalldatetime DEFAULT getdate() NULL
)
GO
```

**update sample data**

I want to get the average daily accesses of this list

```
id;user;PageView;DateHour
10;97697;APP 1;18/12/2017 18:12:00
11;97697;APP 1;18/12/2017 18:15:00
12;97697;APP 2;18/12/2017 18:15:00
13;97697;APP 2;18/12/2017 18:18:00
14;97697;APP 2;18/12/2017 18:25:00
15;15841;APP 1;18/12/2017 18:31:00
16;15841;APP 1;18/12/2017 18:53:00
17;15841;APP 1;18/12/2017 19:04:00
18;15841;APP 1;18/12/2017 19:09:00
19;15841;APP 2;18/12/2017 19:10:00
20;09623;APP 1;18/12/2017 20:15:00
21;23265;APP 1;18/12/2017 21:05:00
22;09623;APP 1;18/12/2017 21:29:00
23;25506;APP 1;18/12/2017 21:49:00
24;20986;APP 1;18/12/2017 22:33:00
25;25623;APP 1;18/12/2017 23:46:00
26;95932;APP 1;19/12/2017 00:02:00
27;29067;APP 1;19/12/2017 00:03:00
28;32337;APP 1;19/12/2017 00:09:00
29;23265;APP 1;19/12/2017 00:16:00
30;09343;APP 1;19/12/2017 00:20:00
31;20901;APP 1;19/12/2017 00:35:00
32;26786;APP 1;19/12/2017 00:47:00
33;24980;APP 1;19/12/2017 00:49:00
34;25996;APP 1;19/12/2017 00:52:00
35;14949;APP 1;19/12/2017 01:03:00
36;54987;APP 1;19/12/2017 01:47:00
37;23265;APP 1;19/12/2017 04:53:00
38;20635;APP 3;19/12/2017 06:14:00
39;25081;APP 3;19/12/2017 06:38:00
40;61660;APP 3;19/12/2017 06:42:00
```

Comment: Sample data, and expected results, will help us help you. For the example you've given each Page only has 1 row, so the average of the value will be the value. An average is calculated by the sum of the values divided by the number of values aggregated. In the above, for example, that would be `7893 / 1` which is (unsurprisingly) `7893`.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for reply, please see **update sample data** on first question

Comment: What about the expected results?

Comment: @Larnu for **PageView** equal to **App 1** I have 24 rows stored divided into two days (18-19/2017). The average is 24/2 = 12 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want the average of a count result set. If so you don't need the second group by. The query will be:

```
SELECT AVG(COUNT) AS avg
FROM
(
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS COUNT,
    T.PageView t 
FROM
    [dbo].[LOG] T 
WHERE
    T.DateHour = (SELECT MAX (B.DateHour) FROM [dbo].[LOG] B WHERE (B.Id = T.Id)) 
GROUP BY
    T.PageView 
) AS counts
```

Comment: thanks for reply, please see update sample data on first question